# Way to control rounding of cell data while row filtering

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a :position column in my dataframe, and I am splitting up into two separate dataframes. One table is for position values that contain 'E' and the other for 'N'. I have having the issue where in the result data tables the rounding of :time is different. In df_final:time my values are being rounded to 5 sigfigs. In df:time the values are preserved at their original precision.

```
df_final = df[occursin.('E',df.position),:]

julia> df_final[2,:time]
3.15053e-7

julia> df[2,:time]
3.150533669638069e-7
```

I have tried many things to try and control the sigfigs for these values as I need them for a comparison in my next block of code. Also encounter the same problem with base filtering.

```
julia> df[occursin.('E',df.position),:][2,:].time
3.15053e-7

julia> df[occursin.('N', df.position), :][2,:].time
3.150533669638069e-7
```

Comment: Have you checked the element types of the `time` column in each DataFrame?

Comment: also have you tried comparing the values (not printing them but comparing)?

Comment: Yes, the root of this problem is that they are comparing as nonequal in the next step of my analysis. Also @PaSTE, they have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my data. My simulation was saving timesteps at different precisions for different elements.